# merging type of EOL, (End of File)

Tags: mysql, eol

I have some files, They're text files and I imported them via `LOAD DATA` mysql command into a database table. But I have problem with some of them.

All of them are 6236 lines:

```
$ wc -l  ber.mensur.txt 
6236 ber.mensur.txt
```

When I import `ber.mensure.txt` , only I have 1611 record in my table. But other files have 6236 row.

My `LOAD DATA` command is :

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/mohsen/codes/haq/translation-tmp/ber.mensur.txt'
INTO TABLE tr_tmp  
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'  
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (aya);
```

I use linux and I'm force to `\n` for end of line(EOL).

When I examine my databse, Some records contains more than one line. I think my end of lines has problem.

Do you have any solution to solve it?

**UPDATE:**

My file is [here](https://send.firefox.com/download/214bc9d171/#E0BKE9VJZBTmqHVmUV6M6A)
By the way, `vim` can know my txt file as 6236 lines.

Comment: So your data is junk. So fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that via :

```
fd = open(YOURFILE,'r')
lines = readlines()
```

It works good.